# X.__getitem__(1) vs type(X).__getitem__(X, 1)

Tags: python, operator-overloading

```
class C:
    data = 'spam'
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print('getattr:', name)
        return getattr(self.data, name) 
X = C()
X.__getitem__(1) // <-- works!
type(X).__getitem__(X, 1) // <-- AttributeError: type object 'C' has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Since `type(X).__getitem__(X, 1)` can't find the `__getitem__` method in class C, shouldn't it call the `__getattr__(self, name)` function?

`X.__getitem__(1)` can't find `__getitem__` in instance and in class so it calls the `__getattr__(self, name)`.

How come one works and one doesn't? I read that special method lookup skips the `__getattr__` function (if called implicitly?) like `X[1]`, however, I am explicitly calling it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part of the [special method lookup docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup) shows exceptions when `__getattribute__` is bypassed.

According to the example there (copied below) with the `__len__` method, the `type(X).__getitem__` from your code would invoke `__getattribute__` from the metaclass, but you haven't defined it.

```
>>> class Meta(type):
...     def __getattribute__(*args):
...         print("Metaclass getattribute invoked")
...         return type.__getattribute__(*args)
...
>>> class C(object, metaclass=Meta):
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 10
...     def __getattribute__(*args):
...         print("Class getattribute invoked")
...         return object.__getattribute__(*args)
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c.__len__()                 # Explicit lookup via instance
Class getattribute invoked
10
>>> type(c).__len__(c)          # Explicit lookup via type
Metaclass getattribute invoked
10
>>> len(c)                      # Implicit lookup
10
```

---

Using this information, the observed behaviour can be explained:

```
X.__getitem__(1) # <-- works!
```

`__getattribute__` from class `C` is called to find `__getitem__`, it returns the `__getitem__` bound to the string `"spam"`. When called with argument 1, the letter `p` at position 1 is returned.

but:

```
type(X).__getitem__(X, 1)
```

`__getattribute__` from metaclass of `C` would be called, but it is not defined there. Result is the `AttributeError`.